# Having a table view as input view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am still struggling with the sign up page for my iphone app - at the moment I am having problems with the gender field.

My idea was that when the user presses the gender field, a table view containing "Male" and "Female" slides up from the bottom and the user then puts a checkmark next to his actual gender. I do not really understand how to correctly obtain this gender table view though.

Currently I have my GenderTableViewCell which points to both a user interaction enabled label and a GenderTableViewController and then I have set the input view of the first to the table view of the latter. In this way a table with "Male" and "Female" actually do slide up when the gender field is touched but as the table is not in grouped style as I specified it to be in GenderTableViewController.xib I have a feeling that I am not on the right track!!

I have been googling and googling but have not been able to find any similar examples - maybe it is not nice to have a table view sliding up? Should I use a UIPicker instead?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a UIPicker instead.  It's going to be much easier to implement, and it is a far more standard experience for the user.

Comment: I am afraid I do not find it any easier to use a picker view. I do not see how I get the picker populated with the two genders from within my gender table cell?

Comment: You need a class to implement the [UIPickerViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol and the [UIPickerViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIPickerViewDelegate.html) protocol.  You can probably have your view controller implement them both if you want, since it's a simple picker.  There's a simple tutorial [here](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uipickerview-creating-simple-picker.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting on this. The only controller I currently have is a table view controller controlling both a username, birthdate, gender, mobile number and a password table cell where each of these cells is an instance of some subclass of UITableViewCell. I find it a bit strange if I now make that overall table view controller the data source of for instance the gender picker inside the custom gender table view cell?

Comment: You by no means need to make the table view controller the data source and delegate for the picker.  You can certainly create your own class that only implements those protocols if you want to (you could even take it one step further and make a data source object AND a delegate object if you felt so inclined).  It is much cleaner to do so, and better from a code separation perspective.

Comment: I agree, but do not have much luck in making it happen it seems. My gender table cell currently has an `IBOutlet UIPickerView *genderPicker` whose dateSource and delegate I have connected to an instance of my `GenderPickerController` (conforms to both `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`) in Interface Builder. I had added one of those yellow view controllers and chosen class `GenderPickerController` in the identity inspector. It does not work though... and cannot see how to wire the stuff up differently :(

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

       return 35;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath // set row value for table

{


   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"anycell"];  
   if(cell == nil)
   {
    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"anycell"] autorelease];
/// UIImageView *imgView=[[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
//  UIImage *img;
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x=10;
    frame.origin.y=5;
    frame.size.width=280;

     if(indexpath.section ==0)
    {
        //img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"textbox1.png"];
        frame.size.height=27;
        txtname=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        txtname.delegate=self;
        txtname.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:211.0/255 green:236.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        txtname.placeholder=@"User Name";
        [txtname setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
        [txtname setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeURL];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtname];
    }
    else if(indexpath.section == 1)
    {
        frame.size.height=27;
        txtpassword=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        txtpassword.delegate=self;
        txtpassword.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:211.0/255 green:236.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        txtpassword.secureTextEntry=TRUE;
        txtpassword.placeholder=@"Password";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:txtpassword];
    }
    else
    {
        frame.size.height=27;
        //frame.size.width=200;
        btnSave=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [btnSave setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"user-save.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnSave addTarget:self action:@selector(saveClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btnSave];

    }
}
if(indexpath.section == 0)
    txtname.text=appDelegate.setObj.username;
else if(indexpath.section == 1)
    txtpassword.text=appDelegate.setObj.password;

UIImageView *imgView=[[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
imgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"textbox1.png"];
cell.backgroundView =imgView;

cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;        
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am not sure how that helps me in doing my gender picker? :}

Comment: Just use that with a UISegementControl